# ReadFromPubSub->CloudStorage->BigQuery: Subscription never decreases in size and only 0.002% seemingly arrive in BigQuery

Tags: python, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

The pipeline is using the `ReadFromPubSub` source to read links to Cloud Storage blobs, reading the events stored in each of those files and then inserting them into BigQuery:

```py
with beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options) as pipeline:
    dlq = DeadletterQueue(known_args.output_dlq)

    pipeline = (
        pipeline
        | "Read PubSub Messages"
        >> beam.io.ReadFromPubSub(
            topic=topic,
            id_label="messageId",
        )
        | "Read Records" >> ReadCloudStorageEvents(deadletter_queue=dlq)
        | "Parse Events" >> ParseEventRecords(deadletter_queue=dlq)
        | "window events" >> WindowOnTimeAndSize(60, 10)
        | "Upload To BigQuery" >> BigQuerySink(project, deadletter_queue=dlq)
    )
```

The issue is that even though the items are being consumed from PubSub at an excellent rate, and the files are being read from cloud storage at an equally good rate, they are simply not being inserted into BigQuery at anything near to the bigquery streaming limits.

The data freshness and system lag keep climbing: [image: lag never drops].

A side-effect of this is that the queue items are not deleted.

The `BigQuerySink` is essentially this:

```py
class BigQuerySink(beam.PTransform):
    def __init__(self, project: str, deadletter_queue: beam.PTransform):
        self.deadletter_queue = deadletter_queue
        self.project = project

    def expand(self, pcoll):
        def yield_from(events: Iterable[Dict]) -> Iterable[Dict]:
            for event in events:
                yield event

        pcoll = (
            pcoll
            | "flatten events" >> beam.FlatMap(yield_from)
            | f"push events to BigQuery"
            >> beam.io.WriteToBigQuery(
                table=lambda event: f"{self.project}:events_v2.{event['type']}",
                schema=lambda table: load_schema(table.split(".")[-1]),
                create_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED,
                write_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_APPEND,
                insert_retry_strategy=RetryStrategy.RETRY_ON_TRANSIENT_ERROR,
                validate=True,
                additional_bq_parameters={
                    "clustering": {"fields": ["accountId"]},
                    "timePartitioning": {"type": "DAY", "field": "receivedAt"},
                },
            )
        )

        # # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59102519/monitoring-writetobigquery
        pcoll[
            beam.io.gcp.bigquery.BigQueryWriteFn.FAILED_ROWS
        ] | "Map to Error" >> beam.Map(
            lambda x: Error(
                message=f"BigQuery exception",
                record={"destination": x[0], "index": x[1]},
                data=None,
                stacktrace=None,
            )
            | self.deadletter_queue
        )
```

Testing with 200.000 elements, referencing files with around 10,000,000 events in total resulted in only around 0.002% of them getting into BigQuery. We are no-where near the quotas, I am not seeing any errors or anything (of which I would see some errors sometimes when a field did not match the schema, but I am seeing nothing).

Any insights into pinning down where this is going wrong would be tremendously welcome. Is there some place to see if the items are failing some validation in BigQuery end therefore not being deleted in the subscription or?

The step that seems to be the bottleneck is the `_StreamToBigQuery/CommitInsertIds/ReshufflePerKey/Map(reify_timestamps)` as is visible in the below picture. Close to a 1000 MB entering that step and only 5 MB exiting (if I am reading the graph correctly):
[image: here]

Update: `WindowOnTimeAndSize`

```
class WindowOnTimeAndSize(beam.PTransform):
    """A composite transform that groups Pub/Sub messages based on publish
    time and outputs a list of dictionaries, where each contains one message
    and its publish timestamp.
    """

    def __init__(self, window_size_seconds, after_count):
        # Convert minutes into seconds.
        self.window_size = int(window_size_seconds)
        self.after_count = after_count

    def expand(self, pcoll):
        return (
            pcoll
            # Assigns window info to each Pub/Sub message based on its
            # publish timestamp.
            | "Window into Fixed Intervals"
            >> beam.WindowInto(
                beam.window.FixedWindows(self.window_size),
                trigger=Repeatedly(
                    AfterAny(
                        AfterCount(self.after_count),
                        AfterProcessingTime(self.window_size),
                    )
                ),
                accumulation_mode=AccumulationMode.DISCARDING,
            )
        )
```

Comment: Maybe it's worth reconsidering your solution and simplifying it. You don't actually need Pub/Sub or Dataflow for this. You're creating additional hops when you don't need to e.g. reading the contents of the files in GCS and then inserting to BigQuery. Instead, you could have a Cloud Function listening to the bucket(s) which get fired when a file(s) arrives. When that happens, the Cloud Function then loads the file directly into BigQuery. Would this meet your requirements?

Comment: An excellent point. The reason this is the way it is, is that getting the events on creation time is not enough for our purposes. We need to replay data from time to time (migration, new fields are interesting etc.), so feeding the events through a PubSub using a format we control allows us to do that. Even if we did that though, the issue would persist however, since the bottleneck seems to be after reading the files and inside the WriteToBiguery (I think)

Comment: but I did miss your Cloud Function argument. I guess I am afraid that when we start throwing the rest of the data we have at this Topic that we'd basically have an eternally triggered cloud function, especially in the very expected replay situation. What would the cost trade-offs be in your experience?

Comment: Another option is to point your Dataflow pipeline directly at GCS and it reads the file once it arrives and writes it to BigQuery.

Comment: the issue, as I see it, is that if we then want to replay these events (that are in the file sin GCS, how would you trigger it if not through a PubSub or some other intermediate layer that you could hit with some script?

Comment: Create a templated Dataflow pipeline which takes the file name(s) as argument(s) and execute it over http. That said, I've worked on many projects where _"replay functionality"_ was engineered for, but was not actually needed by the solution/business.

Comment: I can totally relate to this, however, this project in fact sprung out of the old pipeline not being able to keep up with us replaying data (and it is the primary reason for it). Dataflow seemed like the perfect candidate for us being able to predict cost better vs. infinitely scaling cloud functions (which is not suuper far from the initial design concept).

Comment: _"infinitely scaling cloud functions"_ - why would you need to do this? How often are the files landing in GCS?

Comment: I, I think we are talking past eachother. We don't need it, was the point. We need something that can handle a decent realtime flow of events, and then scale quickly up when we need another migration. But we prefer being able to just lock the amount of instances to a single one, and have predictive cost vs. cloud functions where we can only confide it to a number of concurrent executions, but it is much less efficient at using its resources than Dataflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were some changes to WriteToBigQuery that made the transform very slow. In Beam 2.24.0 (upcoming in a few weeks), the transform should be able to reach higher performance (I've tested ~500-600 EPS per CPU).

Sorry about the troubles. You can use the code at head today, or wait a few weeks for Beam 2.24.0.

Comment: that is excellent news @pablo, what were the previous numbers you were seeing with your dataset? Just trying to compare numbers here. What was the speedup in percentage?

Comment: I had seen some awfully low EPS in workers (~100 or less)

Comment: alright, I'll monitor the beam releases for the update - thank you.

Comment: Can I know the rate for version 2.25.0? I have 28 workers(=48cpus) but merely streaming to BQ with the rate like 500~800 EPS

Answer (score 1):

Your best resource is probably the Dataflow Monitoring Console, specifically when [viewing the pipeline](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/using-monitoring-intf#viewing_a_pipeline) you can click on the individual steps to determine which one is causing the lag. Don't forget that composite transforms can be expanded by clicking on the little v-shaped symbol to drill down into the problematic piece.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I should have mentioned that the point at which the bottleneck seems to appear right now is inside the `beam.io.WriteToBigQuery` which I have very little control over. So I was assuming it was something to do with how I was or wasn't doing windowing that was the issue.

Comment: I updated the original post with the info and a screenshot of what seems to be the bottleneck

Comment: It does seem to be this Reshuffle GBK. What is the windowing being used in `WindowOnTimeAndSize`?

Comment: Hi @robertwb, I've updated the original post with it, but I am windowing on 60 seconds, but in case of extremely high throughput, I wanted to output on each 10 events using the `Repeatedly` and `AfterAny`. Mostly because the original 60 seconds really didn't make a difference.